# NAND flash memory Organization issue

Tags: nand-flash

Organization

- Page size ×8: 18,592 bytes (16,384 + 2208 bytes)
- Block size: 1536 pages, (24,576K + 3312K bytes)
- Plane size: 4 planes × 548 blocks per plane
- Device size:

  - 384Gb: 2192 blocks;
  - 768Gb: 4384 blocks;
  - 1T2: 6576 blocks;
  - 1H2: 8768 blocks;
  - 3Tb: 17,536 blocks;
  - 6Tb: 35,072 blocks

I can't calculate the correct capacity, please help me

below is my calculation

[image]

It should be 384Gb but I figured it is 466Gb , why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers work out if you assume that only the 16k bytes per page are used for storage, and that only 512 blocks per plane are used.

- 16 kB/page × 1536 pages/block = 24 MB/block
- 24 MB/block × 512 blocks/plane = 12 GB/plane
- 12 GB/plane × 4 planes = 48 GB (which is 384 Gbits)

In a typical filesystem, the extra 2208 bytes per page are used for ECC and other housekeeping functions. And the extra 36 blocks per plane are probably reserved for redundancy (replacements for bad blocks).

Therefore, the different device sizes are constructed using 4, 8, 12, 16, 32 and 64 planes, giving nominal capacities of 48, 96, 144, 192, 384 and 768 GB, respectively.